# Microsoft SQL Data Sync 2.0 Agent not listing any databases since server move

Tags: azure

I have SQL Data Sync set up to keep a few databases installed in a remote data centre synchronised to an Azure SQL dB used for BI reporting.
Recently the physical SQL server on the data centre side was replaced and all the databases on it detached and re-attached to a new instance.
I had thought these would all show as "unreachable" in the agent UI and I could then remove and add in the new links. However, the UI on the agent now shows no databases at all (they are still listed in the Azure portal with the original IPs). If I try to add the dB back in with the new connection details it fails with a duplicate dB name being used.
Any ideas how to resolve this?
Thanks

Tried looking for some form on config or manifest on the machine hosting the Agent that might have the connections in there but can't find anything obvious.